# How do I change the primary Accessibility element in a new ViewController?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am implementing VoiceOver accessibility in my iOS App pikSpeak which helps blind people to locate iOS different buttons on the screen.

When I open a new ViewController the first button that Siri announces is the one on the top-left-most corner. However, that is not the primary button that I want the users to hear when they open a new ViewController as it is generally the back button. Rather I want it to be the page heading button.

How do I change the primary accessibility to a UILabel?

Comment: While brittle, it's sometimes helpful to introduce a slight delay between the view load and your screen changed notification.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating solution from [comments by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060291/how-do-i-change-the-primary-accessibility-element-in-a-new-viewcontroller#comment35240368_23060291) [David Rönnqvist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608157) to an answer:</sub>

> Depending on the exact problem you can either put the focus on that element when the view appears or you can manually reorder all of the elements.
>
> To change the focus to a UILabel programmatically:
>
> `UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, yourLabel);`

Comment: Reposting a [comment by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060291/how-do-i-change-the-primary-accessibility-element-in-a-new-viewcontroller#comment35245259_23060291) under the question: *@DavidRönnqvist Thanks for the perfect answer, I looked up the Apple Docs and found out that tis the exact way to resolve the issue, but due to some reasons, I am unable to get that result. When I open a ViewController the first time the Top-Left element is selected :-( . But when I pop to the same VC, it works as expected. Any suggestions?*